# How to easily read xls doc on dynamic site?

Tags: javascript, python, xls

Programming noobie here. I'm working on a website where users fill out a form and based on their input a given value from a big excel sheet is displayed on the page. I know JS, jQuery, HTML/CSS, and Python but I haven't learned how to use any framework like Django yet. I'm wondering how I can most easily read values from the xls doc. It looks like xlrd is a good bet. I'm doing this project on a tight deadline though so I'm not sure I have time to learn a framework like Django and it seems like overkill for something as simple as this. Can I use xlrd for the website without learning a framework? And more broadly, what's the simplest way to implement this solution (i.e. read values from an XLS doc onto a web page)?

Answer (score 0):

Django is a big framework, consider using [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) microframework (it shouldn't take your more than 4 hours to get the basics and put together simple application).

The easiest approach would be to go with Microsoft technology stack - you can expose quite easily Excel sheet as Web Service, so the web page can read it data as JSON or XML.